# phonegap client websocket and vb.net server

Tags: vb.net, websocket

I want to connect my andoid app generated through phonegap to vb.net server, I am facing issue with basic handshaking frame, I am receiveing Sec-WebSocket-Key1 and Sec-WebSocket-Key2 but not able to receive last 3rd part need to resend hand shake frame from server, also it is mentioned in websocket protocol that key 1 and key 2 need to be converted to big endian number, I am also not getting way to do it. It mentioned something like the following,

> The concatenation of the number obtained from processing the
>   |Sec-WebSocket-Key1| field, expressed as a big-endian 32-bit number,
>   the number obtained from processing the |Sec-WebSocket-Key2| field,
>   again expressed as a big-endian 32-bit number, and finally the eight
>   bytes at the end of the handshake, form a 128 bit string whose MD5 sum
>   is then used by the server to prove that it read the handshake.

I am able to do it correctly in php but not find suitable logic in vb.net.

```
$key = pack('N', "155712099") . pack('N', "173347027") . "Tm[K T2u";
echo md5($key,true)."<br>";
```

in short I need above code to be converted to vb.net or c#.